# What is causing TCP Window Full (WireShark) errors sending to WCF service?

Tags: wcf, tcp

We have a WCF data collection service running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine.  Clients are Win 7 x64 boxes and the application is a C# .NET 4 Windows Forms app.  The primary purpose of the service is collecting test results form the clients and serving up reports based on that data.  (It interfaces to a SQL Server instance and an Oracle instance, but that is probably irrelevant.)

Recently as we added more clients we started seeing data transmissions being lost and  "MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint quota (10) has been reached" errors on the service side so we adjusted the parameters up accordingly.

That type of error went away but now we ere getting "Faulted System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel" errors on the server side.  Running WireShark on the server side proved to be an exercise in futility as it just wouldn't stay running... maybe the VM interfered, I don't know.

Running WireShark on the client side yielded more information.  When the send failures occurred WireShark reported several "TCP Window Full" errors.

Here is the binding def from the server side:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="bigBufferBinding"
             portSharingEnabled="false"
             maxBufferSize="1024000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="1000000"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000"
             maxConnections="500"
             listenBacklog="250"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200"
                    maxStringContentLength="65536"
                    maxArrayLength="32768"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And here's the client side:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="bigBuffer_ClientTcpBinding"
             maxBufferSize="1024000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="1000000"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000"
             sendTimeout="00:00:30"
             receiveTimeout="00:00:30">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200"
                    maxStringContentLength="65536"
                    maxArrayLength="32768"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I tried increasing the maxBufferSize, maxBufferPoolSize and maxReceivedMessageSize attributes but any significant increase caused the service to fail to start.  I'm not sure that's where the problem lies anyway.

What do I need to be looking at here?  We don't have a huge amount of data (10 clients sporadically sending anywhere from 60 to 40000 bytes of data to the service) so we surely shouldn't be overwhelming the WCF service.  I'm thinking it has something to do with how TCP is configured but that's just a guess. It's running across a gigabit network with jumbo packets disabled.

We have 15 to 40 data failures per day out of thousands of attempts.  We added retries so the data eventually gets there (2nd try in most cases) - that doesn't really fix the problem but it gets production off my back and we don't actually lose any data.

Just to quell the expected protests and scoldings, we are writing the serialized data to a disk file on failure (twice!) so if the data just can't get to the database we can resubmit it. We never actually lost any data.

Ideas? Any help appreciated, more data available on request.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Still looking for answers to this one.  Due to the underwhelming response I'm thinking it is probably a network configuration issue and not a coding issue, but the jury is still out on that...